# Unable to start service with Intent, Unable to add window -- token null is not valid, is your activity running?

Tags: java, android, service, view

I'm new to Android, I got this error :

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.wmaddviewtest, PID: 6104
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.example.wmaddviewtest.WmNewViewService@345022b with Intent { cmp=com.example.wmaddviewtest/.WmNewViewService }: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?<br/>
    ...... <br/>
 *Caused by: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:774)*
    at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:373)
    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:93)
    at com.example.wma<ddviewtest.WmNewViewService.createWindowManagerView(WmNewViewService.java:64)
    at com.example.wmaddviewtest.WmNewViewService.onStartCommand(WmNewViewService.java:31)
```

I do add user-permission at AndroidManifest.xml.
My AndroidManifest is following:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

-<manifest tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning" package="com.example.wmaddviewtest" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


-<application android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_descriptor" android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:supportsRtl="true" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:allowBackup="true">

<service android:permission="" android:exported="true" android:enabled="true" android:name="com.example.wmaddviewtest.WmNewViewService"/>


-<activity android:name=".MainActivity">


-<intent-filter>

<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>

</intent-filter>

</activity>

</application>

<uses-permission tools:ignore="ManifestOrder" android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>

</manifest>
```

In MainActivity.java:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    showViewBtn = findViewById(R.id.showViewBtn);
    showViewBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(MainActivity.this, WmNewViewService.class);
            startService(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

I add a Custom Service named WmNewViewService.java, following is it's code:

```
private MyView myView;
private WindowManager mWindowManager;
private WindowManager.LayoutParams mParams;
private final static String TAG = "WmNewViewService";
    public WmNewViewService() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        myView = new MyView(this);
        mWindowManager = (WindowManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        createWindowManagerView();
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (myView != null) {
            mWindowManager.removeViewImmediate(myView);
            myView = null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * set Parameters ,and AddView
     */
    public void createWindowManagerView() {
        mParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
        mParams.width = mWindowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
        mParams.height = mWindowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
        mParams.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_PANEL;
        mParams.format = PixelFormat.RGBX_8888;
        mParams.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL |
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE;
        mParams.x = 0;
        mParams.y = 0;
        myView.requestLayout();
        mWindowManager.addView(myView, mParams);
    }
```

also, you can see I new a MyView, and MyView.java is:

```
private View myView;
private Button newViewBtn;

public MyView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init();
}

private void init() {
    myView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.myview, null, false);
    newViewBtn = myView.findViewById(R.id.newViewBtn);
}
```

In addition, I new a myview.xml, myview.xml just a LinearLayout, include a Button, the Button text is "this is a view".

In my activity_main.xml, I only set a button which is clickable.

I just want when I click the button which is in activity_main.xml, then start service, and the service make the button which text "this is a view" show.

I do try postdelay.

Comment: when i see the error info :"android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:774)", i just thought myView.getparent() is null, but i don't know why it's wrong.

Comment: Are you trying to modify the view in your activity from service? If Yes, you should send broadcast from your service to activity and in the receiver change the view.

Comment: I think I don't trying modify the view in my activity from service, I want show a new view(the myview.xml) above the view in my activity, should i send broadcast also?

Comment: meanwhile i looked some code to send broadcast and receiver, I try to use 'sendBroadcast(intent);' instead of 'startService(intent)' now.

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the full package location in AndroidManifest.xml and see if that helps. IE:

```
<service android:enabled="true" android:name="com.exercise.AndroidClient.services.WmNewViewService" />
```

instead of

```
<service android:enabled="true" android:name=".services.WmNewViewService" />
```

(replacing with the correct package location obviously)

Comment: thank you for your reply, i replaced with the correct package location but it still the same error, said that `Caused by: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:774)
        at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:373)
        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:93))`   @ChristianBoler

Comment: It might be worth posting your AndroidManifest.xml, if possible. Also, check the line numbers given by the error.

Comment: the error line is in my custom service, WmNewViewService.java, createWindowManagerView() :`mWindowManager.addView(myView, mParams);`